# Installing two versions of Windows 7 on different partitions

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a Compaq 620 with 4 partitions on the hard drive. The primary partition has Windows 7 installed on it.

I want to dual boot this computer with Windows 7 (Korean version) installed on the other partition. How should I go about doing this?

I do not want the Korean version to interact in any way with the English version. I also don't want to mess anything up so I thought I should ask here first. Please let me know how I should go about doing this, where things might go wrong, and how I can avoid them.
Thank you

Comment: Just install Windows on the other partition. You will have to modify the first installation to present the option to boot to either installation if its not automatically when the installation is complete.  **If you want to do this you will have to mess with something you have no choice**

Comment: It's ok I am willing to play around for the boot order screen, I just don't one installation to damage the other one

Comment: If you select the correct partition its not possible to damage the other installation, in the worst case, you might have to fix the boot loader which is a trivial task.

Comment: it seems Windows 7 reserves some space on the hard drive before the main C drive, I was worried the new korean installation might disturb that part in some way. Do I have worry about that?

Comment: You will have to be more specific then that.

Comment: I meant, Windows 7 reserves some 100MB of space as a hidden partition, as the system partition (which can be seen during the installation screen of Windows 7), I was just worried whether the Korean Windows 7 installation would affect that, in turn affecting my main install.